# ReceiveAndSendReply from two different states

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflowservice, workflow-foundation-4.5

I am wondering how can I implement State machine process so I can call single WCF contract to the process and directly receive a response, having current state of the process (S1, S2 or S3) based on the parameters I send to it.

I have a state machine workflow. There are some variables in the process scope, but the most important is **CurrentState** variable, that holds current state of the process.
We also have **P1** value that controls transitions in our state machine. Its value is received and set in the first state of the process, called **S0**.
**S0** state initializes Workflow, by receiving WCF call with **P1** process parameter. Then, depending on the **P1** value, process goes to state **S1**, **S2** or **S3**.
In state **S1**, **S2** and **S3** we have a single Assign activity, that sets CurrentState to **S1**, **S2** or **S3**.

Is it possible, to have a Receive activity in state **S0** and SendReply activity in states **S1**, **S2** and **S3**? Then I could could return CurrentState of the process directly after transition to S1/S2/S3 is completed? What is the best practice in cases like this?